# Send a document from s3 to docusign for Signature

Tags: docusignapi

I have a use case where I am getting a document from S3 and I want to send it to docusign for signature. I have already implemented the piece where my code is getting the document.

I want to use the embedded signing ceremony for the same. Are there any examples of the same in Golang? I already have a sandbox account and have tested out the API using java.

Ay pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim Cote (who was featured as a [spotlight developer](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developer-spotlight-jim-cote-liberty-fund)) wrote a golang client library that he opened source here - https://github.com/jfcote87/docusign

I have not tried it myself, but you can always fork the code and make modifications as needde or ask Jim if he can help.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out.

Comment: I would anyways need to follow the steps here for the token integration for my prod account right? https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant

Comment: yes, you would need to obtain an OAuth token.
If you have questions about this - please submit them separately. 
Please mark this as answered if your original question was answered.